# Shared Entities in Clean Architecture

Tags: flutter, architecture, clean-architecture

I'm reading into clean architecture and I want to apply it to some software that I wrote. In this software, entities such as `User` and `Group` play a very central role. For this reason, it would make sense to share these entities across the code in order to avoid repetition but it is somehow also against the rules of clean architecture.

What is the right decision to be made in this case? Should I just throw in a "shared/entities" folder in `core`?

The project that I am working on in programmed mainly in flutter, if that's important to the answer.

Comment: I think it's a trade-off between avoiding repetition and coupling.  Once you share those classes you have to redeploy everything that uses them when you make changes.  You have to ask yourself if those classes can be repeated, as long as they don't change often.  How many times will you add fields to User once you've got first and last name?  The answer isn't clean cut.  Know the rules, but break the rules mindfully when appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I know zero about Flutter or Dart (apart from what I just Googled), but it looks like it supports interfaces.

A good approach is not to throw users and groups into a shared folder, but to create some really light-weight representations of them, and throw those into a shared folder / common library.  An interface is a great way to do this because in the interface you can specify the important basics that parts of your application need to generically know about, without adding implementation specific baggage and dependencies.

When designing your interfaces, be sure to be aware of principles like SOLID - especially the [Interface segregation principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) (the I in SOLID).

To elaborate a bit more:

1. Define `IUser` interface
2. Have your `User` class implement `IUser`
3. Have someway of instantiating `IUser` using your implelentations, like `User`.
4. Where your application references `User` - switch this to use `IUser`.

**Update in response to comment**

My usual starting point architecture would be to define DTO's which I share across all layers of the app (UI, Biz Logic / Data Access), basically like what I think you're suggesting.  For me, DTO's are as light-weight as possible - basically information carriers.  These are shared across all layers, in a common package, as per [clean architecture](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html) so that different **layers** of the architecture (e.g. biz logic and data access) are not tightly coupled to each other.

However, users can be bit of a special case in that they can have security / identity / credential related stuff which can become quite specialized and/or implementation & technology specific.  This, I suspect, is partly where @duffymo's comment about tight-coupling comes in.

With my answer I'm basically saying that, yes, you can put DTO's into a common folder - **and** for tricky cases (like Users) you always have the option of defining interfaces on them as well...  e.g. the User DTO might have **properties** which are interfaces rather than concrete properties.

```
class UserInfo
{
  string FirstName { get; set; }
  string LastName { get; set; }
  ITaxData TaxData { get; set; }
}
```

I admit it's entirely possibly I'm over-complicating things with the '(some) DTO properties as interfaces' idea.

Comment: Thanks for this Adrian. I think this may not be the right answer according to clean architecture where DTO's and mapping (if needed) should be user to carry data between layers. Your answer may be useful, but is maybe not clean architecture. What do you think?